# Webpack 4 with Less and MiniCssExtractPlugin using entries

Tags: webpack, less, webpack-style-loader, webpack-4, mini-css-extract-plugin

I have following structure for styles in my application:

**application**

```
- css/
   - bootstrap/
      - boostrap.less -> has (@import "another.less")
      - another.less
   - common/
      - common.less
   - entries/
      - bootstrap.js -> has (import style from "../bootstrap/bootstrap.less")
      - common.js -> has (import common from "../common/common.less")
```

And now I need to create separate CSS-es from styles imported to entries bootstrap.js and common.js.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
{
    entry: {
        "boostrap": ["./css/entries/boostrap.js"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(less)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "less-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "./css/[name].css"
        })
    ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "webpack": "^4.16.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
}
```

When I run webpack I get error below:

```
Entrypoint boostrap = boostrap.js
    [0] multi ./css/entries/boostrap.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] ./css/entries/boostrap.js 48 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] ./css/bootstrap/bootstrap.less 1.41 KiB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

    ERROR in ./css/bootstrap/bootstrap.less
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
    ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:0)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong? It looks like `bootstrap.less` thrown an error during import other less file, but I don't know why.

Thanks

Rafal

PS: Similar issue is reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326241/webpack-4-help-for-less-configuration).

Comment: if you just do `import "../bootstrap/bootstrap.less"`, does it break?

Comment: thanks, but I'm getting the same error unfortunately...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the reason. It turned out that my `boostrap.less` had reference to `glyphicons.less`. Glyphicons imports fonts for extensions: *.eot, *.woff2, *.woff, *.ttf and *.svg and that was my missing part.

`file-loader` or `url-loader` are two possible options. I went for the latter:

> npm install url-loader --save-dev

and add configuration as below:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
{
    entry: {
        "boostrap": ["./css/entries/boostrap.js"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(less)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "less-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)|\.svg($|\?)/,
                use: "url-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "./css/[name].css"
        })
    ]
}
```

Thanks

Rafal

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me! Adding the test and use for url-loader is all I had to change in the config file. I used regex: `test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)($|\?)/,` instead.