# scss file is not loading while using webpack

Tags: webpack, sass

I hope everything is fine over there. I need your help.

My .scss file is not loading in webpack and giving error. I explain everything in detail.

- I have application.scss file in my `assets/css/application.scss` folder.

```
.vertical.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.config.menu {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.site-page {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-family: Lato, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100 !important;
  background-color: $bgcolor;
}
```

- I have imported it in app.scss`(assets/css/app.scss)`

```
@import "../node_modules/fomantic-ui-less/semantic.less";
@import "../node_modules/nprogress/nprogress.css";
@import "application.scss";
```

- Imported this app.scss in app.js `assets/js/app.js`
- Below is my webpack.config.js `assets/webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const PurgecssPlugin = require('purgecss-webpack-plugin');
const globAll = require('glob-all');


module.exports = (env, options) => {
  const devMode = options.mode !== 'production';


  return {
    devtool: devMode ? 'source-map' : undefined,

    context: __dirname,

    entry: {
      app: [
        "js/app.js",
      ],
      dashboard: 'js/dashboard.js'
    },

    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../priv/static"),
      filename: devMode? 'js/[name].js' : 'js/[name].[hash].js',
    },

    devServer: {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      }
    },

    optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            output: {
              comments: false,
            },
          },
          cache: true,
          parallel: true,
          sourceMap: devMode
        }),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}),
        new PurgecssPlugin({
          paths: globAll.sync([
            '../lib/**/templates/**/*.html.eex',
            '../lib/**/templates/**/*.html.leex',
            '../lib/**/views/**/*.ex',
            '../assets/js/**/*.js',
          ]),
         }),
      ]
    },

    plugins: [

      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: "./static",
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, "../priv/static")
      }]),

      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: devMode ? 'css/[name].css' : 'css/[name].[hash].css',
        chunkFilename: devMode ? 'css/[id].css' : 'css/[id].[hash].css',
      }),

      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        jquery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        "window.$": "jquery"
      })
    ],

    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.(sa|sc|c|le)ss$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              options: {
                hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
                reloadAll: true,
              },
            },
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader',
            'postcss-loader',
            'less-loader',
          ],
          sideEffects: true
        },
        {
          test: require.resolve('jquery'),
          use: [{
            loader: 'expose-loader',
            options: 'jQuery'
          },{
            loader: 'expose-loader',
            options: '$'
          }]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jsx?)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "babel-loader"
        },

        {
          test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/i,
          use: [{
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
              name: 'images/[name].[ext]'
            }
          }]
        },

        {
          test: /\.(ttf|woff2?|eot|svg)$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=1024&name=/fonts/[name].[ext]'
          }
        },
      ]
    },

    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '../../theme.config$': path.join(__dirname, 'semantic_theme/theme.config'),
        'jquery': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min')
      },
      modules: ["node_modules", __dirname],
      extensions: [".js", ".json", ".jsx", ".css", ".styl", ".less", ".scss"]
    },

  };
};
```

- Below is my package.json `assets/package.json`

```
{
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "node_modules/.bin/webpack --watch --colors --mode development"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.0.0-alpha5",
    "child-replace-with-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "classlist-polyfill": "^1.2.0",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.4",
    "fomantic-ui-less": "^2.8.4",
    "formdata-polyfill": "^3.0.19",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mdn-polyfills": "^5.19.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "phoenix": "file:../deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:../deps/phoenix_html",
    "phoenix_live_view": "file:../deps/phoenix_live_view",
    "semantic-ui-calendar": "^0.0.8",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "glob-all": "^3.2.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "less": "^3.10.3",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "postcss": "^7.0.21",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

- When I run my project `iex -S mix phx.server` (I am using phoenix and Semantic for UI). Getting below error.

```
ERROR in ./css/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):



@import "application.scss";
^
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):



$bgcolor: #0000FF;
^
Unrecognised input
      in /Users/maheshvuppala/icicle/Work/Code/icicle-2020/assets/css/application.scss (line 3, column 0)
    at /Users/maheshvuppala/icicle/Work/Code/icicle-2020/assets/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
    at /Users/maheshvuppala/icicle/Work/Code/icicle-2020/assets/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /Users/maheshvuppala/icicle/Work/Code/icicle-2020/assets/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/Users/maheshvuppala/icicle/Work/Code/icicle-2020/assets/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
      in /Users/maheshvuppala/icicle/Work/Code/icicle-2020/assets/css/app.scss (line 7, column 0)
    at /Users/maheshvuppala/icicle/Work/Code/icicle-2020/assets/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
    at /Users/maheshvuppala/icicle/Work/Code/icicle-2020/assets/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /Users/maheshvuppala/icicle/Work/Code/icicle-2020/assets/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/Users/maheshvuppala/icicle/Work/Code/icicle-2020/assets/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
 @ ./js/app.js 4:0-25
 @ multi js/app.js
Child mini-css-extract-plugin node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js!node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js!css/app.scss:
```

- Please help me with this, I have tried all possible ways which I got from online. Your solution might help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, a little note: when importing a style that is included in a node_modules package, it's common practice prefix the package name with a tilde:

`@import "../node_modules/fomantic-ui-less/semantic.less";`

Becomes:

`@import "~fomantic-ui-less/semantic.less";`

that would inform the loader that the file is coming from node_modules folder, and the path will be formed automatically.

Now, talking about SASS/SCSS, looks like your MiniCSSExtract Plugin is trying to read your scss files, and it shouldn't happen. You can determine it by looking at the error:

```
ERROR in ./css/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
```

It's a scss file, but it's getting loaded by the mini-css-extract-plugin loader.

Your regex it's trying to load all the stylesheet extensions with a single loader:

`test: /\.(sa|sc|c|le)ss$/,`

**Sass and Less are different formats!**
If you want to import the less file from `fomantic-ui-less` library, then webpack must be instructed on how to load the `less` file extension as well with the `less-loader`, the `sass-loader` by itself cannot do this.

Try the following configuration:

```js
module.exports = {

 module: {
 
  rules: [
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader', // compiles SASS to CSS
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.less$/,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'css-loader',
            'less-loader', // compiles Less to CSS
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,'css-loader'],
        }, 
    ]
 },

plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: devMode ? '[name].css' : '[name].[contenthash].css',
      chunkFilename: devMode ? '[id].css' : '[id].[contenthash].css',
    }),
  ],
};
```

you can find them here: [sass-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/) [less-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/less-loader/)

There are also many examples on how to use the [MiniCssExtractPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#examples) you should check them out!

There's an answer regarding the plugin here:  [Webpack 4 with Less and MiniCssExtractPlugin using entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671425/webpack-4-with-less-and-minicssextractplugin-using-entries)

Anyway it's better to proceed step by step to find any culprit, and most of all, there are plenty of examples on webpack website, for each plugin, you should check them out.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Modified webpack.config as mentioned. Getting below error. Please check this once.
`ERROR in ./css/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src!./css/app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: @import directive requires a url or quoted path
on line 18 of node_modules/fomantic-ui-less/definitions/globals/reset.less
    >> @import (multiple) '../../theme.config';
       ^
`

Comment: This is how I modified webpack.config.js file:

`{
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
            {
              loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              options: {
                hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
                reloadAll: true,
              },
            },
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader',
            'postcss-loader',
          ],
          sideEffects: true
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
        }`

Comment: I've edited the answer, sorry yesterday I haven't noticed that the external file was in less format (the title is asking how to import scss files). It should work now

Comment: I have modified my webpack.config.js file as per your instructions. Getting below error. Note: Babel loader is included file.

`
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js(./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js)

"use strict";
^
Unrecognised input
      in /Users/Work/Code/icicle-2020/assets/node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js (line 1, column 0)
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js 2:26-98
`

Sorry if I am troubling you. I am newbie to this.

Comment: Hi mate, don't worry we are here to help. I apologize but the last time it was late, I uploaded a wrong configuration! Forgive me :-) Now I updated the answer, it should be easy to understand. As you can see, Less/SASS files are managed separately, because each file type needs it's loader. Once it's converted to CSS, the MiniCSS plugin will extract the generated style into many CSS files. Please check your "app" entry configuration, it shouldn't be in one array. If still returns an error, please share your project on github, your config is quite complex to solve without an example project.